# Express midlleware is still calling if path params is not given in url

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have created one authentication middleware to authenticate my routes. I want a middleware not to be called on some specific routes. There is one routes which accepts path params and it is working fine without calling a middleware but when I remove path params from a url it still calls a middleware. Below is the code

```
var authRouter = require('../../../middlewares/authmiddleware');
router.use(authRouter);

router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/getUser/:id', controller.getUser);
router.get('/', authRouter, controller.getTest);
router.put('/logout', authRouter, controller.logout);
```

I have also done something like this

```
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/getUser/:id', controller.getUser);
var authRouter = require('../../../middlewares/authmiddleware');
router.use(authRouter);

router.get('/', controller.getTest);
router.put('/logout', controller.logout);
```

When path params is not given it calls a middleware. I don't want to call a middleware if path params are not provided in url. How to achieve this?

Comment: router.use(authRouter); means always use this middleware. you might want to reconsider that line.

Comment: `router.get('/', authRouter, controller.getTest);` will always call authRouter

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to come over this problem.

1. in `authRouter` itself,check whether params present or not.Based on that you can proceed with next middleware or call next route which handle error for you.

   ```
    authRouter = (req, resp, next) => {

   if (!request.params.someparams) {
       next('route'); //proceed with next route which handle error/required stuff
   }
   //proceed here
   }
   ```
2. Add above stuff as a new middleware before `authRouter`

   ```
   router.get('/', (req, resp, next) => {

     if (!request.params.someparams) {
      next('route'); //proceed with next route which handle error/required stuff
     } else {
       next(); //call next middleware
     }

   }, authRouter, controller.getTest);
   ```

Comment: Riyaj thankyou for an answer but I am specifically looking for this route router.put('/getUser/:id', controller.getUser); I don't want to call authRouter on this even if path params are not given in url, if I give path param then it works fine without calling authRouter